# SQL error missing database (near "123" : syntax error)

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm having a problem creating a table in my database. I get the error message: SQL error missing database (near "123" : syntax error) My code is:

```
    private static void createTable(String account) throws SQLException {
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + account
            + "  (Description           TEXT,"
            + "   Amount            INTEGER,"
            + "   Balance          INTEGER)";
    Statement stmt3 = connection.createStatement();
    stmt3.execute(sqlCreate);
}
```

Im calling the method with createTable(account); where account is 123 (test data).

Comment: account = 123   just  test data to make sure the program works. Its a small part of a program I am working on

Comment: Database tables must begin with a letter. You generally can't have a number as names.

Comment: that was it! thank you

Comment: Besides, it seems like a bad design to have different tables for each account. A common way is to have a single `account` table, containing the data about each account.

Comment: Why are Amount and Balance integer(s)? And what is the semantic difference between the two? Should an account have an id of some kind?

Comment: `123` is not a valid table (or anything else) name. Just bang an underscore on the front: `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _" + account + ...`. btw, nice SQL injection vector! Especially considering the database user would need priviledged access to create a table, the damage that injected code could do is limitless.